# Using \input within a Rubric when using the Curve package

Tags: input, curve-class

I have a CV written in ModernCV and would like to wrap it into Curve, mostly just to see how the two formats differ. After going through the Curve manual it would seem simplest to `\input` my existing content into the rubrics in Curve. 
Except I keep getting `Enter a filename :`

Here is my structure

```
resume.tex          This calls a rubric in a subfolder
rubrics/rubric.tex  This calls a TeX file in the root folder
text.tex            This is the content I wish to include within the rubric
```

Each file has the following content

- `Resume.tex`

  ```
  \documentclass{curve}

  \leftheader{Left}
  \rightheader{right}

  \begin{document}
  \makeheaders
  \makerubric{rubrics/rubric}
  \end{document}
  ```
- `rubrics/rubric.tex`

  ```
  \begin{rubric}{RUBRIC}
  \text{\input{../text}}
  \end{rubric
  ```
- `text.tex`

  ```
  This is some text
  ```

It seems that LaTeX is failing to find the `text.tex` file. I have seen that input is redefined within the `Curve.cls` class and think this is interfering with how `\input` works. Trying `\import`/`\subimport` from the `import` package is also not working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I'd forgotten `\input` works relative to the root of the main file, `resume.tex` in this case. So I had to performs all inclusions relative to this path.

```
root/
  resume.tex        
  rubrics/
    rubric.tex   
  text.tex       Accessed by `text.tex` and file does exist
text.tex         Accessed by `../text.tex` but the file does not exist
```

That is given the file structure above. The relative path `../text.tex` is not converted to an absolute path relative to the `root/rubric` folder but from the `root` folder instead. One is actually accessing a file in the same level as the root folder. One should have used the argument `text.tex` with `\input` instead, so `\input{../text.tex}` becomes `\input{text.tex}` for the example to compile.

Note that using `\subimport` also fails since Curve `\inputs` the rubrics rather then subimports them, and the relative path to absolute path conversion fails as a result.

**Note:** I provided my own answer here as I'd determined a work around but I'm still curious to know how one might resolve this more formally. Does one ask the author of Curve to rely upon `\subimport` instead of modifying `\input`or does one patch it themselves to handle relative imports (I tried the latter to no avail, granted I did not fully understand where I was going wrong just yet) ? I've had similar issues before using `\input` with relative paths and almost exclusively use `\subimport` now but I am curious to know how others resolve this.